# FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2 swift

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending the following payload from Postman:

```
{
    "to" : "serverkey", 
    "data" : {"score":"5"},
    "content_available": true,
    "notification" : {
        "body": "sample21 "
    },
    "priority" : "high"
}
```

and am receiving the error:

```
<FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging receiving notification in invalid state 2
```

I am using content_available as per the docs, so I don't see what the issue is?

Edit: added in  methods as asked by user in comments

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication,  didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],  fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        print("in didReceiveRemoteNotification")
        print("%@", userInfo)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        }
    }

    extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
        // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
        func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
            print("in applicationReceivedRemoteMessage")
            print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing code anything is a guess but do you have didReceiveRemoteNotification in your AppDelegate?

Comment: @Jay updated Q to show appDelegate notification methods